# Proper code design for Android/Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Code design questions

I have a class lets say `Area` that has a private instance variable called `schools` . In the `Area` 's constructor I initialize all my schools because its a time taking process. There is an instance method in `Area` that says group by schools where a list of students are passed. I group these students into their schools and pass back the result.

Is it too much responsibility for this `Area` class that it has to maintain a list of schools as well as is doing the grouping? But my main question is Android related:
I have multiple fragments that needs to use this class. They make use of the number of schools, list of schools as well as grouping them. I dont want to instantiate this `Area` every single time I open a new fragment. Where and how should I be instantiating them in the fragment or another place? I cant make it a singleton because `area` can change and in turn it needs to reinstantiate itself. I cannot call `setSchools` on it as its a one time thing. Any ideas? Is there a design pattern that I can follow?

Comment: hey can you show your code ?

Comment: So how did you go with this?

Answer (score 0):

My thought would be to have a class that handles the creation of the Areas (possibly your Application class).

The Application could then basically hold onto a map of Areas to some form of Area id. If you find an Area that does not yet exist, you could create it at that point and store it in the map for other fragments to use later.

With regard to the sorting of the Students, this doesn't really seem to be the job of an Area.
Perhaps using something like a `StudentManager` would make more sense.

This is how I imagine it (in a simplified form):

```
class Student {
  String name;
}

class School {
  List<Student> students;

  boolean contains(Student) {
    return students.contains(student);
  }
}

class Area {
  List<School> schools;
}

class StudentManager {
  Map<School, Set<Student>> sortIntoSchools(Collection<Student> unsortedStudents) {
    Map<School, Set<Student>> result = new HashMap<>(); // Should use a decorated map here
    for(Student student : unsortedStudents) {
     for(Area area : areas) {
      for(School school : area.schools) {
        if(school.contains(student)){
          result.get(school).add(student);
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure you can improve the StudentManager class sorting but that separation makes some sense to me...

Comment: The thing is I don't see the point of the map at all. Why store all those areas when the user is not even interested in them. Now, we can use an LRUCache and then have a small size but I still feel that is an overhead for what should/could be a simple design

Comment: I think you really have 2 options in this regard. (1) Store the items in memory or (2) Store them in a database/LRUCache and retrieve them when needed. Either way, without knowing more, it seems to me that it would be difficult to avoid pulling all the `Areas` into memory when you need to use them anyway.

I think it all boils down to what is more performant for your particular situation. Keeping all the data in memory, or pulling it into memory when you need it.
This will depend entirely on how this data is being used in your particular application.